# Ant design Upload multiple formats

Tags: reactjs, upload, antd

I am trying to implement Antd Upload component, but I have a problem with the formats that this component accepts.

I'd like to upload  .doc,.docx, and .pdf but I got an error every time if the chosen file is not .docx

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Upload, message, Button } from "antd";

const props = {
  headers: {
    authorization: "authorization-text",
  },
  action: "",
  name: "file",
  multiple: true,
  accept: ".pdf,.doc,.docx",
  beforeUpload: (file) => {
    const acceptedFormats = ["pdf", "doc", "docx"];
    return acceptedFormats.includes(file.name.split(".")[1])
      ? true
      : Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "block",
        width: 700,
        padding: 30,
      }}
    >
      <h4>Upload Documents</h4>
      <>
        <Upload
          {...props}
          onChange={(response) => {
            if (response.file.status !== "uploading") {
              console.log(response.file, response.fileList);
            }
            if (response.file.status === "done") {
              message.success(`${response.file.name} 
                               file uploaded successfully`);
            } else if (response.file.status === "error") {
              message.error(`${response.file.name} 
                             file upload failed.`);
            }
          }}
        >
          <Button>Upload File</Button>
        </Upload>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @slideshowp2 It just said that 'FILENAME' file upload is failed. And I am using like preview before upload, and when is correct file it is green background,and when is not it is red. So only for .docx is green and I am not getting any errors.